# Empty Binary Publishing not working correctly while Tridion Publishing

Tags: 2013, publishing, binary

We have uploaded 0kB .xhtml file as binary component in Tridion and are trying to publish the binary using AddBinary.

```
Engine.PublishingContext.RenderedItem.AddBinary(binaryComponent, structureGroup)
```

When we publish the binary it is getting deployed as a 1kB file with NUL character.

Our requirement is to publish this as empty binary of 0kB.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to publish a binary with 0 kb ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, and what have you tried so far? Is the output 1Kb or a single byte? (In which case, perhaps a string terminator) Is it a kilobyte of NUL characters?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this :

```
Engine.PublishingContext.RenderedItem.AddBinary(item.GetAsStream(),filename,filename,null,"MIME Type");
```